# what does this mean in C int (*ptr[2])[4];

Tags: c, pointers

I want to know what is the meaning of the definition

```
int (*ptr[2])[4];
```

If i print the size of "ptr", it displays 16. 
Also on my machine size of integer pointer is giving 8, where as size of integer is 4.

If i redifine ptr as ,

```
int (*ptr[2]); then also, size of ptr is 16.
```

so questions are

1. what is the meaning of definition int (*ptr[2])[4];
2. How do i initialize ptr?

Answer (score 6):

Use [the right-left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) to read such declarations.

`int (*ptr[2])[4]` is an array of 2 pointers to arrays of 4 integers.

> If i print the size of "ptr", it displays 16. Also on my machine size of integer pointer is giving 8

This is because `ptr` is an array of 2 pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Q2 **How do i initialize ptr?**

E.g,

```
int a[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
int b[4] = { 6, 7, 8, 9};
int (*ptr[2])[4] = { &a, &b };
int i;
for(i = 0; i<4;++i){
    printf("%d ", (*ptr[0])[i]);//a
}
printf("\n");
for(i = 0; i<4;++i){
    printf("%d ", (*ptr[1])[i]);//b
}
printf("\n");
```

,

Comment: Is this initialization correct? `int (*ptr[n])[m];` where `n` and `m` are taken from as user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

`int (*ptr[2])[4];` is an array which has 2 elements, the type of each element is `int (*) [4]`, that stands for an pointer which point an array which has 4 element.

this is equal to `typedef int (* PTR) [4]; PTR ptr[2];`

```
typedef int (*arrayOfNPointers)[N];

So, if this is right, it is a data type describing an array of N pointers to int.
```